# Shouldn't there be an HTML5 tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Apparently HTML5 isn't a tag. Should it be created?

Comment: The thing to do would be to point to some questions where you feel the tag is warranted - that gives folks something to discuss. Right now, "Should we have [x] tag?" just leads to "Well, I don't know, where would we use it?" - so some examples would be very helpful.

Comment: I just posted a question for which it was relevant (Video tag). I couldn't use that tag as I don't have a high enough rep.

Comment: @jchwebdev If your question is the only one that should be tagged with it, then this tag is useless. If you can point out a dozen or two questions like that, then OK, tag may make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Your original question isn't actually about HTML5 (or Drupal actually, it's about a relative path issue), you just happen to be using an element that wasn't available before that version.

I don't think adding a tag is a good idea since it doesn't apply to the question. If there are (let's say) half-a-dozen or more *other* questions that are clearly about HTML5 in conjunction with Drupal, then yes, it would make sense to add it. I haven't come across any such questions, if you have some examples please edit them into the question.

Comment: There are a handful of questions about the new HTML5 form elements, and related (like `placeholder`).  But, I am too busy to search for them.

Comment: @MPD actually http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=html5 returns pretty nice list, but I will not dare to decide which is *really* about html5, and which only happens to mention it, but is not truly version dependent.

Comment: I can only say that, regardless of the relevance of my particular example, an HTML5 tag seems like an obvious choice for -any- web development platform.

Comment: @jchwebdev if you think html5 is obvious for all modern Drupal questions, then you just prove html5 tag would be useless - if it applies to everything, you can't effectively use it for filtering. And filtering is the main (if not the only) purpose of tags.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we should create the tag. Essentially, because we actually have a specific close reason for that type of question

> Questions on programming, PHP, SQL, etc. that do not relate directly to Drupal are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.

HTML would fit nicely into that list, as would HTML5. If a question *really* is about html 5, it's actually off-topic on the site! So no, I don't think the tag should be created.

In addition, had the tag truly been needed, it would have organically been created anyway. There's almost 1000 users with high enough reputation to create the tag, and those users, (since they have higher rep) are the most active on the site. Despite that, not one of them appears to have had need for the tag.

Comment: One last thing and I'm done. Where you wrote, "it would have organically been created anyway." I disagree. Novices don't know what they don't know. And experienced people don't ask. From what I've seen, the Drupal community is not exactly the most 'tech-forward' group of guys (how many sites still run D6?) If you limit tags to what is common, you can miss out on innovations. In fact, I am surprised that HTML5... which has been around for a good while now... is -not- a bigger part of the community's vocabulary. No offense intended.

Comment: You could be right, I could be wrong. Here's a challenge for you: What is a good HTML5 question, that is specifically Drupal related? I loaded up http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=html5 and looked through the first page of 15 question. I found exactly 0 that would be appropriate to tag html5. Either they were about a Drupal api (form or filter), or they were unclear on the question. I challenge you, start by finding a single good question, and we have something useful to discuss.

Comment: @jchwebdev You're missing the point somewhat - we don't create tags until they're required for a question. As we still don't have a list of questions that would benefit from this tag, it hasn't been created yet. That's it. It has nothing to do with the greater community's 'vocabulary', of _course_ we've all been using HTML5 for a long time now. I'm sure we all use angular for our frontend, too, but that doesn't mean we have to create a tag for it. I think you're just unfamiliar with what we use tags for